# Alternative to openinviter

Tags: php, import, contacts

My host does not allow open inviter to get contacgts from yahoo, gmail etc.  Are there any php-based script anyone knows of that would not include an install, ie. that could merely be placed in a directory.  Many thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed that if you run the subquery by itself, it returns the two IDs you expect, and not all four IDs?

Comment: Please don't edit questions into completely unrelated questions. If you want to ask something different, just open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/dangerouse/cloudsponge-lib-php/